# How to find index of element of one list in another list which includes the same elements?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to code in python this simple task (part of a bigger project):

I have two lists where the first one, let's say `A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is sorted and the second one, let's say `B = [3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 5]` is not sorted. What I want to achieve is to obtain the value of the index for each element of the sorted list `A` in list `B`. For example, I want to come with the result of index `i = 3` when I search for the element `A[5] = 6`. I have implemented in the simple way as follows:

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        if A[i] == B[j]:
            index = j
```

I would want to come up with a way which reduces it to only one loop instead of these two nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that all the values in `B` are unique, one way would be to create a dictionary that maps the values in `B` to their indices.

```
b_dict = {}
for i, b in enumerate(B):
    b_dict[b] = i
```

Then, loop over `A` and get all the values from `b_dict`.

```
a_indices = [b_dict[a] for a in A]
```

With your lists, we get

```
A: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B: [3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 5]
a_indices: [2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 3]
```

This solution is O(n) as opposed to the others, which are O(n^2), and will therefore be much faster on large lists.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible solution is,

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = [3, 4, 1, 6, 2, 5]
x= [B.index(i) for i in A]

#To store the result in a dictionary to map value and corresponding index.
a=dict(zip(A,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list.index()` method to find the index of a specific element within a list:

```
indices = {}
for elem in A:
    indices[elem] = B.index(elem)
# {1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 5, 6: 3}
```

Comment: This is still O(n^2), is it not?

Comment: It is still O(n^2), yes, but only uses one for loop. Externally, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in A:
  index = B.index(x)
```

Here index is the index varaible at each iteration.

To save in a dict:

```
indices = {}
for x in A:
  indices[x] = B.index(x)
```